# JavaScript - Understanding Method Chaining with return DOM elements

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, chaining, method-chaining

I'm trying to understand Javascript chaining with a return DOM element. 
I'm not sure how to do this.

This is my code:

```
        (function () {
            function MyQuery(selector) {
                if (!(this instanceof MyQuery)) {
                    return new MyQuery(selector);
                }

                this.nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

                for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
                    this.nodes[i] = this.nodes[i];
                }

            }

            MyQuery.fn = MyQuery.prototype = {
                parent: function () {
                    return this.nodes[0].parentNode;
                },
                color: function(setColor) {
                    this.nodes[0].style.color = setColor;
                    return this;
                }
            };

            window.myQuery = window.$ = MyQuery;

        })();
```

Call Methods:

```
myQuery(".mySpan").parent(); 

// Returns .. <div>

myQuery(".mySpan").parent().color("red");

// TypeError: myQuery(...).parent(...).color is not a function
```

HTML:

```
    <div>
        This DIV has some content.
        <span class="mySpan">This is a span</span>
        more content here.
    </div>
```

I'm not sure why it would give me a TypeError, I have the parentNode which is the **div** all I want to do is set the color text of that div.

Comment: `this.nodes[i] = this.nodes[i];` - wait what?

Comment: you probably want to `return new MyQuery(this.nodes[0].parentNode);` in the parent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make chainable methods available, you must *not* return a DOM element but rather an instance of your `MyQuery` class that has this method.

```
function MyQuery(selector) {
    if (!(this instanceof MyQuery)) {
        return new MyQuery(selector);
    }

    if (Array.isArray(selector)) {
        this.nodes = selector;
    } else {
        this.nodes = [];
        if (typeof selector == "string") {
            var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
            for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                this.nodes[i] = nodes[i];
            }
        }
    }
}

MyQuery.prototype.parent = function () {
    return new MyQuery([this.nodes[0].parentNode]);
};
MyQuery.prototype.color = function(setColor) {
    this.nodes[0].style.color = setColor;
    return this;
};
```